# Border for image won't show

Tags: javascript, css, angular, nativescript

i am using nativeScript and i am trying to add a border to an image but the border won't appear. why does this happend?

the image does get the css, if i set another properties they are in effect

```
<StackLayout>
    <img style="border: 10px solid black;" [src]="currentAttraction.image"/>
</StackLayout>
```

there are not any errors, it's just the border won't show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [Source](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/styling#border-basics)

`<StackLayout>
    <img style="border-width: 10;border-color: black;border-style: solid;" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/large-beautiful-drops-transparent-rain-260nw-668593321.jpg"/>
</StackLayout>`